# Can I insert Tensorflow trained model into arduino?, and how?

Tags: tensorflow, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm planning to make a device which can distinguish between the right and the wrong gait. So, our team bought Arduino, IMU sensor, Bluetooth module.
Although we are not good at designing code, we wanna try to use Tensorflow for distinguishing.

Unfortunately, Arduino uses C++ code, but Tensorflow is based on Python code.
My friend tells us to buy a raspberry-pi for using Tensorflow.

Should we buy a raspberry-pi or can we find out the way to insert Tensorflow library into Arduino?

P.S We don't care a great deal about accuracy because we are just students.

Comment: Are you sure arduino would be powerfull enough to user TensorFlow wich is quite resource consuming...  You can still have a look at this link : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/models.py

Comment: Actually, we're gonna train the model by using a desktop computer, and then we are just inserting the trained model(library) into Arduino. By doing so, I heard that it could work.